# IllegalArgumentException pointerindex out of range ICS (HorizontalScrollView)

Tags: android, android-widget, native, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a weird exception (the stacktrace is as follows)

```
06-28 01:50:52.900: E/Crittercism(8804): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
06-28 01:50:52.900: E/Crittercism(8804):    at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
06-28 01:50:52.900: E/Crittercism(8804):    at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:1974)
06-28 01:50:52.900: E/Crittercism(8804):    at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onTouchEvent(HorizontalScrollView.java:561)
06-28 01:50:52.900: E/Crittercism(8804):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5604)
06-28 01:50:52.900: E/Crittercism(8804):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2054)
06-28 01:50:52.900: E/Crittercism(8804):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1815)
06-28 01:50:52.900: E/Crittercism(8804):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2060)
06-28 01:50:52.900: E/Crittercism(8804):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1829)
06-28 01:50:52.900: E/Crittercism(8804):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2060)
06-28 01:50:52.900: E/Crittercism(8804):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1829)
06-28 01:50:52.900: E/Crittercism(8804):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2060)
06-28 01:50:52.900: E/Crittercism(8804):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1829)
06-28 01:50:52.900: E/Crittercism(8804):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2060)
06-28 01:50:52.900: E/Crittercism(8804):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1829)
```

The weird part of it is that I **never(ever!!!!) call getX(int index)**, just event.getX() or event.getY(). 
And this bug is exclusive to ICS (4.03 and 4.04)

The interesting, but less weird part is that this is almost exclusive to Sony devices:

[error distribution per device models](http://oi50.tinypic.com/hvuek9.jpg)

I have reviewed all the other proposed similar questions, but in every case the problem is with getX(someIndex or id).
Can anyone shed some light on this?